# How to check an Android device is HDPI screen or MDPI screen?

Tags: android, size, screen

I want to check this to fetch different images by internet. How to do that?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

```
density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

// return 0.75 if it's LDPI
// return 1.0 if it's MDPI
// return 1.5 if it's HDPI
// return 2.0 if it's XHDPI
// return 3.0 if it's XXHDPI
// return 4.0 if it's XXXHDPI
```

Comment: Density values described at: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @SteD is it possible to tell what a device is going to be? eg consider the case where the dpi is 140 in the middle of the bucket range? does it round down or up?

Comment: tvdpi is about 1.3

Comment: for nexus 6p i am getting 3.5 , which category will it fall into ?

Comment: oneplus3T has 2.625, what should we consider that in?

Comment: 3.5 Also. This doesn't definitively answer the question.

Comment: Check my answer with interval approach.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64948456/5752473

Answer (score 190):

You can check the screen density with:

```
switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    // ...
    break;
}
```

**EDIT** Be aware that as Android evolves, other values should be included in the `switch` cases. As of this edit, this includes `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV` and `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH`. Consult [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) for the latest info; I'm not going to bother maintaining this answer.

Comment: It's supposed to exist in SDK level 4 (platform 1.6) and up. What SDK level are you using? (In SDK 3, you can use `density` as suggested by SteD.)

Comment: I need to target platform1.5. The below answer maybe fit for my request.

Comment: The below answer is now the above answer, need to be more generic ;)

Comment: FYI, with some new devices (like the Nexus 7), you should also include DENSITY_TV.

Comment: @annie - Good point. Thanks. As of API level 16, it should also include `DENSITY_XXHIGH`. I added a disclaimer to the answer to cover all future cases. :)

Comment: looks like those values are in order. so you can use sequence of `if(dpi >= DisplayMetrics...)` if you don't want to miss specific dpi's.

Answer (score 21):

As of 2018, you can use the below method -

```
    public static String getDeviceDensityString(Context context) {
    switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            return "ldpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            return "mdpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            return "hdpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_260:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_280:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            return "xhdpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_340:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_360:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_420:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_440:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            return "xxhdpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_560:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
            return "xxxhdpi";
    }
}
```

But as @Ted pointed always consult the official docs before using

Comment: According to android documentation this will be also correct approach.
This should be correct approach but should be refactored when new DENSITY_? values will be added in the api.
Until than check my answer with density intervals: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64948456/5752473, also everyone correct me if I am wrong with interval approach.

Answer (score 5):

From the above answers, I combined them and created the below function:

```
    public static String getDeviceDensity(Context context){
    String deviceDensity = "";
    switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            deviceDensity =  0.75 + " ldpi";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            deviceDensity =  1.0 + " mdpi";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            deviceDensity =  1.5 + " hdpi";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            deviceDensity =  2.0 + " xhdpi";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            deviceDensity =  3.0 + " xxhdpi";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
            deviceDensity =  4.0 + " xxxhdpi";
            break;
        default:
            deviceDensity = "Not found";
    }
    return deviceDensity;
}
```

Now, on which device you want to get the density information and which folder it will be used, just add the above method in that activity and add the below line in onCreate

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Log.d("Screen Density: ", Helper.getDeviceDensity(this));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**You should always check the interval not only break point values!**

**According to android documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics**

**Check it like this in Kotlin:**

```kotlin
    when {
                val density: Float = context?.resources?.displayMetrics?.density

                // ldpi
                (density <= 0.75f) -> mulFactor = 0.75f

                // mdpi
                (density >= 0.75f && density <= 1.0f) -> mulFactor = 1.0f

                // hdpi
                (density > 1.0f && density <= 1.5f) -> mulFactor = 1.5f

                // xhdpi
                (density > 1.5f && density <= 2.0f) -> mulFactor = 2.0f

                // xxhdpi
                (density > 2.0f && density <= 3.0f) -> mulFactor = 3.0f

                // xxxhdpi
                (density > 3.0f) -> mulFactor = 4.0f

         }
         return mulFactor;
```

Answer (score 2):

For React Native to check which size is currently of device

```js
import { PixelRatio } from 'react-native';   
 switch(PixelRatio.get()) {
      case 1:
      return "mdpi";
      case 1.5:
      return "hdpi";
      case 2:
      return "xhdpi";
      case 3:
      return "xxhdpi";
      case 3.5:
      return "xxxhdpi";
    }
```

Comment: This will not work. `PixelRatio.get()` will return a range of values depending on the display size set in Android settings, and the dpi. Those values will not co-incide with the exact values you've chalked out.

Answer (score 1):

On some devices (mine is Galaxy Tab3), both density and densityDpi return strange values like 1.33(density), 213(densityDpi). So my solution is to add these flag :

> <item type="bool"
>   name="is_mdpi">[bool]</item>
>  <item
>   type="bool"
>   name="is_hdpi">[bool]</item>
>  <item
>   type="bool"
>   name="is_xhdpi">[bool]</item>
>  <item
>   type="bool"
>   name="is_xxhdpi">[bool]</item>

to 4 values.xml files, put these under corresponding res/values-[xxx]/ folders.

Comment: 213dpi is a well-known density, "tvdpi": http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers