# Check the folder "res" in use in android app

Tags: android, size, screen, directory, screen-resolution

When you start an android application, the operating system detects the screen resolution and uses the graphics included in the folder `mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi` or `xxhdpi`.

My question is: is there any way to know which folder to use android?

for example, would be perfect if I could get a variable that indicates the value `"mdpi"` or `"xxhdpi"` ...

I searched but I always find ways to get the resolution, and I want to be sure which is the folder "res" that will use Android.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method hope this helps you

```
private String getTheDeviceType(Context mContext) {
        try {
            switch (mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                return "ldpi";
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                return "mdpi";
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                return "hdpi";
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                return "xhdpi";
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                return "xxhdpi";
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
  case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
  // ...
  break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
 // ...
break;
  case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
// ...
break;
  case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
// ...
break;
 }
```

and also refer this.
[How to check an Android device is HDPI screen or MDPI screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099550/how-to-check-an-android-device-is-hdpi-screen-or-mdpi-screen)