# Specifications for AVD that matches the Note 3

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create my app's layout on Galaxy Note 3. I found contradictory information on which layout Note 3 uses and I don't have a device so I cannot check myself.

Basically, I read that people are saying that Note 3 uses:

- `large-xhdi`
- `xlarge-hdpi` (doubt this is the one!)
- `normal-xhdpi`
- `layout-sw400dp`
- and some other weird ones not worth mentioning

Would anyone be kind either to tell me which resource directory is the correct one?

This can help you: [finding DPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099550/how-to-check-an-android-device-is-hdpi-screen-or-mdpi-screen), [finding screen size type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/determine-device-screen-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-using-code).

Comment: `layout-sw400` is not a valid resource directory. It also is not comparable to the items earlier in your bulleted list. And using screen density as a direct determinant of a layout resource is a serious code smell. Whether you use `-large` or `-swNNNdp` (for whatever value of `NNN` makes sense for your UI) for your layouts should not depend one iota on what the Galaxy Note 3 happens to use.

Comment: To clarify that last sentence, I mean that it should not depend upon the Note 3's screen density.

Comment: @CommonsWare My mistake, forgot to add `dp`. Fixed now. The reason for this question are my efforts to create an emulator for Note 3 so that I can check the layout on it. Layouts for regular `layout-sw600dp` and `layout-sw720dp` devices are nice, and oddly I cannot find anywhere either AVD configuration for Note 3 or which resources it uses.

Comment: IMHO, asking "how do I create an AVD that matches the Note 3" would have been a better way of phrasing your question. Alas, I don't have a Note 3 to confirm the width and height in `dp`. Samsung offers the Note 3 in [their Remote Testing Lab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action#), so you could try that.

Answer (score 2):

Note 3 has 5.7 inch display with resolution  1920 x 1080, so should be `xhdpi`

[image]

See [this table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2)

Remember that generalized size takes precedence over generalized density.

Comment: This is what I had in mind as well. Do you have Note 3 to check on the actual device if it's really `large-xhdpi`? I am asking because some users reported that Note devices take one layout for Android 4.0+ and another layout for Android older than 4.0.

Comment: No, I haven't Note 3. If older Android versions on the same device use different layout probably is due to a bug, but I'm wondering how its possible for a note 3 got an Android version older than 4.0. Note 3 is a new device and as far as I know should be distributed at least with Android Jelly Bean.

Comment: Hm maybe I made a mistake about SDKs. But I am positive I've read here people complain about Note start taking resources from a different directory. Was odd to me as well. Anyway, thanks for your help. I will hire someone with Note 3 to test the screen and accept this solution if you're right.