# Putting screen densities into the correct bucket

Tags: android

A set of six generalized densities:

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

From the wiki pages of each phone display

Scaling down into the buckets i.e if the ppi is 300 that would go into the hdpi bucket as it less then 320?

```
Galaxy S3 306ppi -> bucket hdpi
Nexus 4  318ppi -> bucket hdpi
Nexus 5  445ppi -> bucket xhdpi
Nexus 5X 432ppi -> bucket xhdpi
Nexus 6  493ppi -> bucket xxhdpi 
Nexus 6P 518ppi -> bucket xxhdpi
```

Is this the correct way to work out buckets for screen sizes.

The reason I asked is because I have created the following value directory resources:

```
values-hdpi/dimens
values-xhdpi/dimens
values-xxhdpi/dimens
values-xxxhdpi/dimens
```

In the `dimens.xml` I have different margins and set the dp depending on the bucket size i.e.

```
<dimen name="network_quantity_margin_top">100dp</dimen>
```

I am interested to know if this is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> The reason I asked is because I have created the following value directory resources. (...)
>   In the dimens.xml I have different margins and set the dp depending on the bucket size. (...)
>   I am interested to know if this is the correct way to do this.

I'm not sure why you want different margins specified in `dp` depending on the density. Specifying the margin as `dp` once, for the baseline density, already handles all other densities for you, meaning that the physical size of the margin will be the same when displayed on any device.

If you used `px` instead of `dp` (but don't), then you would have to do the scaling for different screens yourself.

> Scaling down into the buckets i.e if the ppi is 300 that would go into the hdpi bucket as it less then 320?

Yes, but not because it is less than 320. If there was a rule of thumb I would say it is rounding to the nearest generalized density. See this illustration of how Android roughly maps actual densities to generalized densities (figure is not exact):

[image: generalized densities]

Relevant part of [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) is this:

> Each generalized size and density spans a range of actual screen sizes and densities. For example, two devices that both report a screen size of *normal* might have actual screen sizes and aspect ratios that are slightly different when measured by hand. Similarly, two devices that report a screen density of *hdpi* might have real pixel densities that are slightly different. Android makes these differences abstract to applications, so you can provide UI designed for the generalized sizes and densities and let the system handle any final adjustments as necessary.

So again, you shouldn't really care *how* Android does this if you are just writing an app. What you should care about is:

- specify all [layout dimension](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params) values in `dp` or with `wrap_content`/`match_parent`, as appropriate (text can be in `sp` to additionally match the user preference, but nothing other than text),
- think about different layouts depending on [physical size](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#SmallestScreenWidthQualifier) and [orientation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#OrientationQualifier) of the screen,
- provide bitmap resources for different [densities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#DensityQualifier), just to avoid blurry or pixelated artifacts (because Android will scale them to have the right physical size if you use `dp` or `wrap_content`).

Android will [lookup the best matching resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch), and [then transparently handle](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms) any scaling of the `dp` units, as necessary, based on the *actual density of the screen in use*. The conversion of `dp` units to screen pixels is simple: `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`.

<strike>Note the *actual* density as opposed to *generalized* density.</strike> The latter is <strike>only</strike> a convenience for the developers, since it would be impossible to provide drawables for every screen out there. This way developers need to provide only 3 or 4 sets of graphics, while Android picks the closest fit and adjusts it further for the needs of that particular device. (Nowadays it's possible to use one vector drawable instead of many pre-scaled raster graphics, meaning better quality and less size.)

> Is this the correct way to work out buckets for screen sizes.

No, it is not. According to [Google device metrics](https://design.google.com/devices/) all devices you listed fall into buckets higher than you expected:

```
Galaxy S3    NA        NA
Nexus 4     318     xhdpi
Nexus 5X    424    xxhdpi
Nexus 5     445    xxhdpi
Nexus 6     493   xxxhdpi
Nexus 6P    515   xxxhdpi
```

I took some other devices from that list, and plotted how different devices are falling into density buckets depending on their actual physical density.

[image: density buckets of some Android devices]

```
Chromebox 30            101      mdpi
Chromebook 11           135      mdpi
Samsung Galaxy Tab 10   149      mdpi
Nexus 7 '12             216     tvdpi
Android One             218      hdpi
Chromebook Pixel        239     xhdpi
Nexus 9                 288     xhdpi
Nexus 10                299     xhdpi
Moto X                  312     xhdpi
Nexus 4                 318     xhdpi
Nexus 7 '13             323     xhdpi 
Moto G                  326     xhdpi
Dell Venue 8            359     xhdpi
LG G2                   424    xxhdpi
Nexus 5X                424    xxhdpi
HTC One M8              441    xxhdpi
Nexus 5                 445    xxhdpi
Nexus 6                 493   xxxhdpi
Nexus 6P                515   xxxhdpi
LG G3                   534    xxhdpi
```

You can see, that with some notable exceptions, the rule that the closest generalized density is selected, holds.

The exceptions being Nexus 6 and 6P, that are listed as `xxxhdpi`, even though LG G3 has a higher physical density and still is far from 640px/in. Android One is `hdpi` but it is only slightly denser than Nexus 7 '12 which is `tvdpi`. Chromebox 30 and Chromebook Pixel (admittedly, not Android) are assigned to buckets `mdpi` and `xhdpi` even though they are physically lower than `ldpi` and `hdpi`, respectively.

Comment: I thought you explained that very well. Especially the graph that was very clear.

Comment: Fantastic answer. However, *"Note the actual density as opposed to generalized density"* - not exactly. AFAIK, All dp calculations are done on metrics.Density. On my Moto E4, that is "2", which means 2x160 = 320 dpi. The device reports actual pixel densities of Xdpi=294.967, Ydp=295.563, but width and height dp of root view w/o adornments are 360x568; 360 x 2 = 720, which is the device width in pixels. All dp measurements are derived from that approximate Density, not actual XYdpi.  The end result is that areas of "fixed" dp size vary slightly if measured with ruler on different devices.

Comment: ... So you are correct in so far as device sets metrics.Density to an accurate measurement of its density; which means that it *could* be more accurate than the "xhdpi bucket" the device (here Moto E4) is within. However, it is up to the device to report that. In this case, "Density=1.75" (x160 = 280 dpi) is what emulator defaulted to when I entered E4's pixels and screen diagonal size. But the actual device vendor made a different choice.One advantage for vendor of choosing a more common Density is apps may only have been tested on popular densities; could be inferior layout on odd sizes.

Comment: NOTE: In java that would be `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;` I'm testing via Xamarin C# where naming is converted to .Net standards.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, thanks for enlightening me. Indeed, [calculations are based on `DisplayMetrics.densityDpi`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/ResourcesImpl.java#546), which seems to follow the `DisplayMetrics.density * 160` formula. I have read too much into the docs I quoted. Current docs just say: "system selects the appropriate bitmap based on the screen's dpi. If you don't provide a density-specific resource for that density, the system picks the next best match and scales it to fit the screen"

Comment: I should've used [a permalink](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/1194b0bdfed798cae594c6e80c13855ea6618f3b/core/java/android/content/res/ResourcesImpl.java#546) for my previous comment, instead of linking to `master`.

Answer (score 10):

> I am interested to know if this is the correct way to do this.

You are *mostly* correct.

The problem lies in this part:

---

The reason I asked is because I have created the following value directory resources:

```
values-hdpi/dimens
values-xhdpi/dimens
values-xxhdpi/dimens
values-xxxhdpi/dimens
```

In the dimens.xml I have different margins and set the dp depending on the bucket size i.e.

```
<dimen name="network_quantity_margin_top">100dp</dimen>
```

---

The purpose of `dp` gets defeated by defining folders like `values-hdpi/dimens`. **Density Pixels, by design, are device-agnostic** - **100dp** on a device with **dpi = 240** will look **just as wide/long** on a device with **dpi = 480**. So, if you want your app to look consistent, do not provide different dimensions for different screen densities.

The correct way to think about this is to realize that the only resource that is affected by varying screen densities is `drawable`. A `drawable` on a screen with dpi = 240 will look **twice as big** compared to a screen with density = 480. I am sure that you're providing folders like `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` etc. to deal with this. For everything else, and especially dimensions, use `dp`. For text sizes, use `scaled-pixels - sp`.

More importantly, you should worry about the range of different screen sizes that are available for android. How would you use all the extra screen real-estate on a 10 inch device compared to a 5 inch phone? Qualifiers such as `-normal`, `-large`, `xlarge` should be of more interest to you.

To summarize:

- consider all devices of a certain screen size the same - their screen densities are irrelevant when using `density pixels`.
- for every `drawable` resource you use, place their scaled versions in the buckets you wish to support. Remember that, if you don't provide resources for a certain bucket (say `drawable-hdpi`), android will scale down your drawables from `drawable-xhdpi` folder (provided drawable-xhdpi is defined). The reverse is also true: if you have placed all your drawables in `drawable-xhdpi`, android would **scale-up** your drawables on a `xxhdpi` device. The result will be blurry graphics - because of scaling-up.

I know that its a bit of a steep slope here :). So, if you need to clarify some more, leave me a comment.

Comment: A drawable will look twice as big, only if the layout specifies its size in `px`, otherwise Android will scale it to have the same size, but the image might be blurry. The reason for folders like `drawable-hdpi` is not having the right physical size of graphics, but having them displayed in high quality across devices.

Answer (score 6):

From the Android documentation:

### [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

> In some cases, you will need to express dimensions in dp and then
>   convert them to pixels. Imagine an application in which a scroll or
>   fling gesture is recognized after the user's finger has moved by at
>   least 16 pixels. On a baseline screen, a user's must move by 16 pixels
>   / 160 dpi, which equals 1/10th of an inch (or 2.5 mm) before the
>   gesture is recognized. On a device with a high-density display
>   (240dpi), the user's must move by 16 pixels / 240 dpi, which equals
>   1/15th of an inch (or 1.7 mm). The distance is much shorter and the
>   application thus appears more sensitive to the user.
>
> To fix this issue, the gesture threshold must be expressed in code in
>   dp and then converted to actual pixels. For example:

```
// The gesture threshold expressed in dp
private static final float GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP = 16.0f;

// Get the screen's density scale
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
// Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
mGestureThreshold = (int) (GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP * scale + 0.5f);

// Use mGestureThreshold as a distance in pixels...
```

> The [DisplayMetrics.density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density) field specifies the scale factor you must
>   use to convert dp units to pixels, according to the current screen
>   density. On a medium-density screen, [DisplayMetrics.density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density) equals
>   1.0; on a high-density screen it equals 1.5; on an extra-high-density screen, it equals 2.0; and on a low-density screen, it equals 0.75.
>   This figure is the factor by which you should multiply the dp units on
>   order to get the actual pixel count for the current screen. (Then add
>   0.5f to round the figure up to the nearest whole number, when converting to an integer.) For more information, refer to the
>   [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

you have to handle the resources regarding the screen width in dp not dpi(dot per inch)

for example nexus 5 1920 X 1080 480 dpi it uses xxhdpi
and nexus 6p 2560 X 1440 560 dpi it uses xxhdpi too not xxxhdpi !!

to handle it use the smalest width resource "drawable-swXXXdp"

---

width in dp = width in pixle / (dpi/160)
dp= 1440/(560/160) =~ 411

```
create drawable-sw411dp
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)

Answer (score 1):

### **When speaking about Android devices, PPI == DPI**

**PPI (*Pixels Per Inch*) and DPI (*Dots Per Inch*) mean the same thing** since they are a measure of the **density** of the screen; thus, your approach about PPI vs DPI is correct.

A detailed explanation can be found [here](http://tekeye.biz/2013/android-dpi-dip-dp-ppi-sp-and-screens). The key part of the article is the following:

> The screen density is quoted as **Pixels Per Inch**, PPI, and is the
>   number of pixels that fit into an inch. The higher the number then the
>   sharper images look on the display, therefore consumers consider a
>   high PPI figure an advantage when buying a device. Sometimes the
>   figure is quoted as **Dots Per Inch**, DPI ...

Comment: OP's approach is correct only in the way that ppi means dpi. Otherwise, there's much that should be discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but this may be useful to other readers. Screen density and the "bucket" Android uses to pick a resource from can be confusing. Google's documentation is pretty dense, and it takes alot of work to distill it down to something useful when writing code. Partly because there are several factors and they're telling you everything about screen density and dips. But the short answer is this.

Basically, dpi is your defining factor, (if you rely on other factors like small/medium/large), this is not your answer. Otherwise, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5099588/193467) answer quite helpful and simple. Here is some code I have collated from various sources that I run on app startup to determine display information.

The screen density tells me what dpi level the device supports.

```
float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Next I have a simple device metrics method to tell me about the screen. (Note, I am using Timber logger).

```
protected static void checkDeviceSize(AppCompatActivity context) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
    float dpWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
    String dpiName = getDpiName(density);
    Timber.e("density  :" + density + " [" + dpiName + "]");
    Timber.e("height dp:" + dpHeight + ", (" +outMetrics.heightPixels + "px)");
    Timber.e("width dp :" + dpWidth + ", (" + outMetrics.widthPixels + "px)");

}
```

I also have this simple helper method that determines the DPI name to support the method above.

```
public static final String DPI_LDPI = "ldpi";
public static final String DPI_MDPI = "mdpi";
public static final String DPI_HDPI = "hdpi";
public static final String DPI_XHDPI = "xhdpi";
public static final String DPI_XXHDPI = "xxhdpi";
public static final String DPI_XXXHDPI = "xxxhdpi";
public static final String DPI_TVDPI = "tvdpi";

private static String getDpiName(float density) {
    String result = "undefined";
    if (density < 1.0) {
        result = DPI_LDPI;
    } else if (density == 1.0f) {
        result = DPI_MDPI;
    } else if (density <= 1.3f) {
        result = DPI_TVDPI;
    } else if (density <= 1.5f) {
        result = DPI_HDPI;
    } else if (density <= 2.0f) {
        result = DPI_XHDPI;
    } else if (density <= 3.0f) {
        result = DPI_XXHDPI;
    } else if (density <= 4.0f) {
        result = DPI_XXXHDPI;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhszwkcay2A) from 2013 is still relevant today.