# Drawing on Canvas based on device density

Tags: android, screen-density

I am working on a project in which I am drawing views on screen programmatically. I want set the `LayoutParams`  based on device density. The views should be drawn in large size in high end devices and small in low density devices. Is there any multiplier value which can be used for varying densities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing on Canvas issue in high end devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988804/drawing-on-canvas-issue-in-high-end-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766229/5476209 by this you can get if device is high or low or medium density screen resolution.

Also check this code if you want to make a generic code that work for most of all devices then go here http://www.androidwarriors.com/2016/01/how-to-find-different-devices-screen.html

Below is simplest code snippet that can get device density, it returns integer value

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();    
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);    
int screenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
```

0.75 - Low density, 1 - medium density , 1.5 - high density and 2.0 - extra high density

Comment: I want a generic code obviously. But I am confused about the multiplier value I should use to make it work in all devices.

Comment: As per my knowlege you have to make your own method , you can create your own parameterized method by taking this returned integer value by above snippet and then use your logic @Jas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988804/drawing-on-canvas-issue-in-high-end-devices .This is another question I posted last day. It contains the code snippet I am using. Please check that