# Samsung Galaxy Note 8 Drawable Folder

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, screen-density

I'm wondering what drawable directory the Samsung Galaxy Note 8 will pull from running Android apps?

The device is 521 ppi. xxhdpi is for ~480 ppi and xxxhdpi is for ~640 ppi, so I'm assuming it will be one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galaxy Note 8 is an xxhdpi device.

Comment: "xxhdpi is for ~480 ppi and xxxhdpi is for ~640 ppi" - it will round down, there are TONS of devices, so it doesn't make sense to make folders for each ppi device.

Comment: I don't think that is always true in practice. You could be right though. I think a 620 dpi device may round up for example, not down. I wanted to test on an actual device to be sure.

Comment: Re: not making folders for specific devices: I'm not doing that, I just wanted to know the folder for the note 8 so I could figure out asset sizes. It was more of a curiosity thing, wanting to know if it's 3x or 4x. I don't know how you'd even make folders for each device since you're right there are tons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739945/putting-screen-densities-into-the-correct-bucket/33789580 - i found this article, it's quite useful as they discuss sizes and densities.

Comment: Yea I've read that before. So you can see it's not always rounding down. Also based on that list you can see the Nexus 6 and 6P are xxxhdpi even though they are lower ppi than the Note 8 (or the LG G3 in that list).