# React native resources issues

Tags: android, react-native, android-screen-support

I am an Android App Developer and started working on React-Native from last one month. I have questions, for those I am unable to find solution:

1. does react-native use `sp` instead of `dp` for font-size and what if we want to use dp for font-size.
2. I want to provide `hdpi`, `xhdpi` and `xxhdpi` dimens for a layout, how to do this?
3. How to provide separate dimens for 7 inch tablet, 10 inch tablet and phone? For some purpose, I want to implement isDeviceTablet() method for react-native, how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find below answers to your questions:

1) Does react-native use sp instead of dp for font-size and what if we want to use dp for font-size.

Yes react-native use sp for font-size so does the android, so you don't need to change it to dp. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textSize

2) I want to provide hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi dimens for a layout, how to do this?

No specific folders are there to support dimens directly. In this case you should use concept of PixelRatio. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html

For providing responsive font size, you can check below link for reference: [React Native Responsive Font Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628677/react-native-responsive-font-size)

3) How to provide separate dimens for 7 inch tablet, 10 inch tablet and phone? For some purpose, I want to implement isDeviceTablet() method for react-native, how to do that?

Create a method for checking isDeviceTablet() method in your android code and then call that method in your js file.

For checking isDeviceTablet(), Please check below link for reference:
[Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

For calling android method in your js file please follow below steps:

**Create a UtilityControllerModule class:**

```
public class UtilityController implements ReactPackage {
    public UtilityController(Activity activity) {

    }

    public UtilityController() {

    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(new UtilityControllerModule(reactContext));
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

**Create a module class:**

```
public class UtilityControllerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public UtilityControllerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "UtilityController";
    }


    @ReactMethod
    public void isTablet(Callback callback) {
        boolean tabletSize = reactContext.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
        Log.e("isTablet >>", "" + tabletSize);
        callback.invoke(tabletSize);
    }
}
```

**Now in your js file where you want to call this method:**

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

var UtilityController = NativeModules.UtilityController
```

**and now call isTablet(),**

```
componentDidMount(){
    UtilityController.isTablet((isTabletCallback)=>{
      console.log("isTabletJs>>",isTabletCallback);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found the 3rd and 2nd answer for your question.
To know what dimensions do you have to use and how, read this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html
And to for to know if for example the device is a tablet you could use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-detection
I hope it works for you!!! :D

Comment: 3rd answer is wrong, take an example of 
Nexus 4- 720x1280 (318ppi)
PixelRatio is - 2
below condition will consider it as tablet
if(this.pixelDensity === 2 && (this.adjustedWidth >= 1920 || this.adjustedHeight >= 1920)){

}


References-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739945/putting-screen-densities-into-the-correct-bucket/33789580
https://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_4_e960-5048.php
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html

Comment: Then this issue should be reported. Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

I think this one can help you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-dimensions

- font size automatic scale base on screen size with

```html
<Text style = {{fontSize: responsiveFontSize(2), color: PRIMARY_COLOR}}>Abonnement</Text>
```

2: is normal size

- image scale

```html
<Image style = {{width: responsiveWidth(100), height: responsiveHeight(100)}} source={CONNECTION_BACKGROUND}/>
```