# TextView, which is generated dynamically, taking extra padding on top?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a base activity where I set content layout by creating a layout dynamically. setContent method looks like this

```
lateinit var topView: TextView
override fun setContentView(layoutResID: Int) {
    val screenRootView = RelativeLayout(this)
    screenRootView.setLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
    // Create your top view here
    topView = TextView(this)
    topView.setLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
    topView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    topView.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
    var dimen = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.size_30dp)
    if (AppHelper.isHomeScreen) {
        topView.setPadding(10, dimen.toInt(), 10, 15)
    } else {
        topView.setPadding(10, 15, 10, 15)
    }
    topView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.green))
    val inflater = this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val screenView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, null)
    screenRootView.addView(screenView)
    screenRootView.addView(topView)
    super.setContentView(screenRootView)
}
```

From an activity, I sent a layout ID. xml of the layout is as following

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/screen_background_normal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_back_navigation"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size_30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title of Toolbar"
        android:textColor="@color/text_blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/text_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Hello World" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

TextView of the setContent() method will show me network status. I've check network status like this way

```
fun drawLayoutfromNetworkStatus() {
    var pos = 0
    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        checkStatus(false)
        //Add again check for full connected
        val handler = Handler()
        val r = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                    checkStatus(true)
                } else {
                    pos++
                    checkStatus(false)
                    if (pos == 10) {
                        pos = 0
                        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                    } else {
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000)

    } else {
        checkStatus(true)
    }
}

private fun checkStatus(isAvailable: Boolean) {
    if (isAvailable) {
        if (topView != null) {
            topView.text = getResourceText(R.string.connected)
            topView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.green))
            topView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out))
            Handler().postDelayed({
                topView.visibility = View.GONE
            }, 1000)
        }
    } else {
        if (topView != null) {
            topView.clearAnimation()
            topView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            topView.text = getResourceText(R.string.waiting_for_network)
            topView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.orange))
        }
    }
}
```

After running the application textView on the top which I set dynamically, is taking extra padding on the top of it. 
[image]

What would be the problem and how can I solve this?

UPDATE:
I've already used it on another activities. It works fine for layout of those activities but not for this layout..

Comment: It is genereted dynamically. See 4th line of setContentView() method

Comment: `topView.setPadding(10, dimen.toInt(), 10, 15)` this line you set 30dp my guess that y its taking more padding at top. What is the size of this `R.dimen.size_30dp` Value.?

Comment: Size of R.dimen.size_30dp is 30dp for xxhdpi

Comment: |DId you set required dimensions for low density devices?

Comment: Yes. I've added it for 5 types of density.

Comment: Check your device density what you are currently running? Its maybe type of xxhdpi resolution device. Find more here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739945/putting-screen-densities-into-the-correct-bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739945/putting-screen-densities-into-the-correct-bucket)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177703/discussion-between-mohamed-mohaideen-ah-and-shafayat-hossain).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
topView = TextView(this)
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)topView.getLayoutParams();
 layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 20);
 topView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here

```
var dimen = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.size_30dp)
if (AppHelper.isHomeScreen) {
    topView.setPadding(10, dimen.toInt(), 10, 15)
} else {
    topView.setPadding(10, 15, 10, 15)
}
```

you are saying that in other activites works ok because those aren't the home screen maybe? you are giving padding 30dp on top if it `isHomeScreen`

change it to just

```
topView.setPadding(10, 15, 10, 15)
```

> it looks like that you don't understand what I am saying, change your function to that

```
lateinit var topView: TextView
override fun setContentView(layoutResID: Int) {
    val screenRootView = RelativeLayout(this)
    screenRootView.setLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
    // Create your top view here
    topView = TextView(this)
    topView.setLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
    topView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    topView.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

    //the if from here has been removed !!!!
    topView.setPadding(10, 15, 10, 15)
    //so you will have the same paddings for all of your activites WoW!!!

    topView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.green))
    val inflater = this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val screenView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, null)
    screenRootView.addView(screenView)
    screenRootView.addView(topView)
    super.setContentView(screenRootView)
}
```

Comment: @shafayathossain you tried to change the above code just to `topView.setPadding(10, 15, 10, 15)`?

Comment: your image clearly shows that there is a different margin on top, because if it was the space from anywhere else it wouldn't be colored green as your background color of the textview

Comment: This is a base activity. All activity extends this. Other activites works fine. If margin is problem, then there must be problem on other activities.

Comment: @shafayathossain ok then, upload also your code from other `activities` and the `AppHelper.isHomeScreen`

Comment: I've a splash activity. xml and activity class is at https://pastebin.com/RyvCaUzv
and screenshot of the screen is https://ibb.co/cAThMU

Comment: ok now give us a screenshots with the paddings of textview to `0` or `10,15,10,15` that i have suggested an hour ago

Comment: this is image of that padding.

Comment: still I don't see that you have done the change that I have suggested to you

Comment: That's why I've said that it doesn't works. Nothing changes here.