# How to specify the text size only for certain screen dimensions and smaller?

Tags: android, android-layout, text, text-size

I only want a `TextView` to be **`"12sp"`** if the screen has a pixel density of `hdpi` or less. Otherwise, I want the **`TextSize`** to be defined by Android Studio, as it usually happens when the attribute `textSize` is not defined specifically. How do I do that?

Currently, I have a **`dimens.xml`** file in **`values-hdpi`** with the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <dimen name="text_size">12sp</dimen>
<resources>
```

this is in the relevant **`TextView`** in my XML file:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/version_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size">
```

Currently, the `TextView` in all screen dimensions has the size **`12sp`**

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/ssp

Comment: You can specify size in dimen.xml file density wise.

Comment: But wouldn't that still apply to all screen dimensions, rather than those of a screen dimension and less?

Comment: as per your requirement- you need to check programmatically 

refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099550/how-to-check-an-android-device-is-hdpi-screen-or-mdpi-screen