# Seperate Jetpack composable functions based on screen density

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying out jetpack compose library how to create separate compose functions based on screen density, screen orientation, locale in an organized way

```
class Success(private val body: String) : MyViewState() {
    @Composable
    override fun buildUI() {
        Padding(padding = 16.dp) {
            Text(text = body, style = +themeTextStyle { body1 })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can just use something like this:

```
val resources = LocalContext.current.resources
val density = resources.displayMetrics.density
val densityDpi = resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi
Log.d(TAG, "density: $density - $densityDpi")
```

And do your logic...
You can also compare `densityDpi` with `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_*`.
Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099550/how-to-check-an-android-device-is-hdpi-screen-or-mdpi-screen).

Comment: where do you get "resources" from?

Comment: Sorry... It's from `LocalContext`. I edited my answer ;)